# obtain row count of subset from data table

Tags: r, data.table

```
dt= data.table(ID1=rep("A",10), 
               ID2=rep("B",10), 
                sig=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-1,0))
dt=rbind(dt,dt)
```

```
 dt
    ID1 ID2 sig
 1:   A   B   0
 2:   A   B   1
 3:   A   B   0
 4:   A   B   0
 5:   A   B   0
 6:   A   B   0
 7:   A   B   1
 8:   A   B   0
 9:   A   B  -1
10:   A   B   0
11:   A   B   0
12:   A   B   1
13:   A   B   0
14:   A   B   0
15:   A   B   0
16:   A   B   0
17:   A   B   1
18:   A   B   0
19:   A   B  -1
20:   A   B   0
```

I want to extract sig=1 to sig=-1 and from sig=-1 to sig=1. 
Output should look like:

```
output1=dt[2:9]
output2=dt[9:12]
```

```
 2:   A   B   1
 3:   A   B   0
 4:   A   B   0
 5:   A   B   0
 6:   A   B   0
 7:   A   B   1
 8:   A   B   0
 9:   A   B  -1
```

My final output needed is

```
cluster1=dim(output1)[1]
cluster2=dim(output2)[1]
```

I have close to 5000 such rows from which i need to extract blocks of data. Any pointers in the right direction would help

Comment: I tried aa=dt[dt[,sig!=0],][1];  dt[dt[,sig==(aa[,sig] |-1*aa[,sig])]] But that does select from sig=1 to sig=-1.

Comment: Can you please add desired output too?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Have edited the question

Comment: But what should happen after row #9? It seems to me that you are basically subseting the whole data set except the first and the last rows

Comment: The second block would be from row 9 to 12 and the third block would be from 12 to 19 and so on

Comment: So you are basically taking the whole data set. Where are these blocks are supposed to be put?

Comment: I need them only temporarily. I need to do row count of each block

Comment: So row count per block is your desired output. Your question is completely different. Please rephrase so it will be clear.

Comment: Including the desired output- not just the title

Comment: The output doesn't match your parameters...... the output you put only matches from `sig=1` to `sig=-1`

Comment: @Amit I dont follow your comment

Comment: Please update your question to include full expected output for the example. You've omitted the 12-19 part that you only mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would maybe do...

```
wDT = dt[.(sig = c(-1,1)), on="sig", .(w = .I), by=.EACHI]
setorder(wDT, w)

#    sig  w
# 1:   1  2
# 2:   1  7
# 3:  -1  9
# 4:   1 12
# 5:   1 17
# 6:  -1 19

switchDT = wDT[, .SD[1L], by=.(g = rleid(sig))]

#    g  w
# 1: 1  2
# 2: 2  9
# 3: 3 12
# 4: 4 19
```

So (thanks @DavidArenburg for a simplification)...

```
switchDT[, diff(w) + 1L ]
# [1] 8 4 8
```

---

A shorter way, also suggested by David, would skip creating `switchDT`:

```
wDT[!duplicated(rleid(sig)), diff(w) + 1L ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Extremely elegant and i got to learn new tricks.